# Trying to move a column from one df to another, getting duplicate axis error but have cleared duplicates from both dfs

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to move one column to another `df` as a new column using an index containing similar values. Before clearing duplicates the `df 'players'` had 425 rows (401 after) and the 'fppm' df had 532 rows (525 after).
I'm still getting the ValueError listed below saying I cannot reindex from a duplicate axis and have no clue where to go from here. Any help is appreciated!!

I've tried deleting duplicates from both dfs to no avail. Don't know where to go from here.

```
fppm = pd.read_csv('FD Fppm.csv', index_col=0)
players = pd.read_csv('Fanduel NBA Players - 10232019.csv', index_col=0)

players[players.duplicated()]

players = players.drop_duplicates()
fppm = fppm.drop_duplicates()


players['fppm'] = fppm['FD Fppm']
```

`"ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"`

Comment: Please read the following documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

Comment: I guess you need [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: Join ended up working great @Aryerez! I did have to take out the index_col parameter when I read in the csvs and just set the index as parameters for join.